# How to use localization.strings with XCTest unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a project, nothing deep. Just some extensions and want to test my localization function.

[image]

But when I run my unit test, the localization defaults to the given string, and is not localized based on the Localizable.string.

Is there a proper way to test up the tests to use test ONLY resource files? I don't want this included as part of the package framework on GitHub.